# PSTricks insert logo

Tags: graphics, pstricks

I am using PSTricks with `beamer`. I couldn't insert logo (`MU.jpg`), but it works if I'm not use `pstricks` package. So what can I do if I also need to use `pstricks` package?

Comment: use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`

Answer (score 2):

You can transform MU.jpg into MU.eps (MU.ps). It can be done by many freeware programs, for example GIMP (http://www.gimp.org/ ), available for many platforms.

Comment: @PeterJansson  This is an answer.  If you're using `pstricks`, any images you load need to be in `eps` format.  Though what would be nice is if Przemyslaw provided and link or suggested such particular software such as [using convert available here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Comment: @PeterJansson: it _is_ an answer

Comment: I agree with @A.Ellett that `convert` is _the tool_. Usage is simple: `convert MU.jpg MU.eps`